# ValueError: Data Cardinality is Ambiguousx sizes: 7000 y sizes: 7500

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

Hello Good People of Stackoverflow,

Im facing an issue of training a MLP model, i believe it is due to my Spliting of the data and applying the SMOTE oversampling, however i am really facing a issue in understanding what could be causing my imbalance of x and y sets.

```
`**Split the data into training, validation, and test sets**

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed)
X_dev, X_test, y_dev, y_test = train_test_split(X_test, y_test, test_size=0.5, random_state=seed)



**Print the shapes of the training, validation, and test sets**
print("Training set shape:", X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print("Validation set shape:", X_dev.shape, y_dev.shape)
print("Test set shape:", X_test.shape, y_test.shape)`


Training set shape:(7000, 5) (7000,)
Validation set shape: (1500, 5) (1500,)
Test set shape: (1500, 5) (1500,)

SMOTE
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
smote = SMOTE(random_state=1)
X_train_resampled, y_train_resampled = smote.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)


Resampled training set shape: (13536, 5) (13536,)
Training set shape: (7000, 5) (7000,)
Validation set shape: (1530, 5) (1530,)
Testing set shape: (1500, 5) (1500,)`

MLP

`from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

from sklearn import neural_network
model = neural_network.MLPClassifier(random_state=1)

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense,Dropout
#random state

import random
random.seed(1)

import numpy as np #numpy depends on random
np.random.seed(1)

import tensorflow as tf #tensor depends on numpy
tf.random.set_seed(1)

#first layer
model.add(Dense(4,input_dim=4,activation = "relu")) #8 neurons for 2nd layer 
model.add(Dropout(0.1)) # Outof8neuronsDrop1 neuron randomly per epoch. #regularization for generalized(more useful) solution
#output layer
model.add(Dense(1,activation = "sigmoid")) #for 2 category, 1 or 0 only or model.add(Dense(2,activation="softmax"))

#model.add(Dense(n,activation="softmax")) # for n category.`
`model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer="adam",metrics=["accuracy"]) #loss is during epoch #metrics measures cost at the end of epoch
#dont use accuracy when false negative and false positive is not symmetrical
#optimzer is adaptive learning rate , learning rate depends via momentum(adam optimzer formula).

b = 5
h = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=b,epochs=100)


ERROR MESSAGE
ValueError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-328-208a2cc838ae> in <module>
      1 b = 5
----> 2 h = model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size=b,epochs=100)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in _check_data_cardinality(data)
   1846             )
   1847         msg += "Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples."
-> 1848         raise ValueError(msg)
   1849 
   1850 

ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 7000
  y sizes: 7500
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.`
```

I have tried changing my splitting of data however i have been stuck on this problem for awhile now, i would appreciate any help or advice i can get thank you!

Comment: Where is Y_train defined? Note the capital Y.